# Из файла(блокнот) вывести массив через переменную х на консоль

Tags: c++, c

Здраствуйте в файле(блокнот) находится массив(10 элементов) и нужно переписать данные последовательно
в переменную х и распечатать в консоли. Вот мой код но вылетает ошибка

```
int x;
fopen_s(&f2, "f2.txt", "r");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fscanf(f2, "%d", &mas2[i]);
    x = mas2[i];
    cout << x << " ";
}
fclose(f2);
```

Comment: Вы бы написали. какая... и еще - массив-то зачем? Почему вместо `fscanf(f2, "%d", &mas2[i]);
    x = mas2[i];
    cout << x << " ";` не просто `fscanf(f2, "%d", &x);
    cout << x << " ";`? и если уж C++, то зачем использовать сишные функции, а не `ifstream f2("f2.txt"); for... f2 >> x; cout << x; ...`?

Comment: @Harry, tag `C`.

Comment: @0andriy Ну какой там С при `cout << x <<` в вопросе?...

Comment: @Harry, вот именно. *С этого мы и начнём наш сегодняшний урок!*